# SQL Server grouping consider null as equals to all values

Tags: sql-server, null, grouping

In SQL Server, I'm trying to group matching rows by ids. Null is considered a wildcard.

Explanation: What does matching rows mean?

Matching rows means – just if all columns of two rows match.

Match column mean – same value ('A' = 'A') or null value for each value ('A'/'B'/'C'/... = NULL).

In my example:

Row 1 matches Row 2 – Because:

```
First column: 'A' = 'A'
Second column: 'B' = NULL
Third column: NULL = 'C'
```

Row 1 does not match Row 4 :

```
First column: 'A' = 'A'
Second column: 'B' != 'D'
Third column: NULL = NULL.
```

The comparison failed because the values in second column that do not match.

Can anyone help me with the SQL?

For example:

For creating the test table:

```
create table test_table 
(
    id int,
    column1 varchar(20),
    column2 varchar(20),
    column3 varchar(20)
);

insert into test_table (id, column1, column2, column3) values 
(1, 'A', 'B', NULL),
(2, 'A',NULL, 'C'),
(3, 'A', 'B', 'D'),
(4, NULL, 'D', NULL),
(5, 'A', 'B', 'D');
```

The table for example

[image]

This is the expected result:

```
group id 1: {1,2}
group id 2: {1,3,5}
group id 3: {2,4}
```

these rows can not join into one group: {1,2,3}.

Example of the expected result in a table:

[image]

I tried this answer:

```
   SELECT
    T1.id as row_id,
    T2.id as row_id
FROM
    test_table AS T1
    INNER JOIN test_table AS T2 ON
        (T1.column1 = T2.column1 OR T1.column1 IS NULL OR T2.column1 IS NULL) AND
        (T1.column2 = T2.column2 OR T1.column2 IS NULL OR T2.column2 IS NULL) AND
        (T1.column3 = T2.column3 OR T1.column3 IS NULL OR T2.column3 IS NULL)
WHERE
    T1.id < T2.id
```

the result table:
[image]

So I can see that row 1 matches row 2, 3, 5 - but I can't see that rows 2 and 3/5 cannot join into the same group. 
What I want is a result where I can see that rows 1,3, 5 can be in the same group because they all match, but the matching between rows 1 and 2 need to be in other group, because row 2 does not match rows 3 and 5.

Comment: I almost feel like you have a normalization problem, and that you maybe should have one junction table per pair of columns.  I'm not sure that any answer you get here would scale very well.

Comment: You did a good work explaining what a match is, but never explain what a group is. You can have 2 matching but what mean 3 matching? I dont understand what the group_id is on the table sample and how is related to the text sample

Comment: I test your data and your query and looks good https://rextester.com/BDI28000, The result doesnt match to your desire output but match your description. So not sure what is the problem you have.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the result table in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Again you have a condition `T1.id < T2.id` so that dont match your desire output., Again you have to expand in the matching explanation because my test match your description

Comment: It's no correct to write `and not the group: {1,2,3}` as for 1=2

Comment: Check my answer. And answer my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the following approach:

- Find all different values from `column1`, `column2` and `column3`. These values are the possible candidates for `NULL` values in your columns.
- Generate all possible combinations for `NULL` values using generated different values
- Select only duplicate rows
- Generate groups numbers using `DENSE_RANK()`

Statement:

```
;WITH ValuesCTE ([column]) AS (
   SELECT column1 FROM #test_table WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
   UNION 
   SELECT column2 FROM #test_table WHERE column2 IS NOT NULL
   UNION 
   SELECT column3 FROM #test_table WHERE column3 IS NOT NULL
), ReplaceCTE AS (
   SELECT 
      t.id, 
      CASE WHEN t.column1 IS NULL THEN c1.[column] ELSE t.column1 END AS column1, 
      CASE WHEN t.column2 IS NULL THEN c2.[column] ELSE t.column2 END AS column2, 
      CASE WHEN t.column3 IS NULL THEN c3.[column] ELSE t.column3 END AS column3
   FROM #test_table t
   LEFT JOIN ValuesCTE c1 ON t.column1 IS NULL
   LEFT JOIN ValuesCTE c2 ON t.column2 IS NULL
   LEFT JOIN ValuesCTE c3 ON t.column3 IS NULL
), DuplicatesCTE AS (
   SELECT column1, column2, column3 
   FROM ReplaceCTE
   GROUP BY column1, column2, column3
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT
   r.id,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY r.column1, r.column2, r.column3) AS grp
FROM ReplaceCTE r
RIGHT JOIN DuplicatesCTE d ON (r.column1 = d.column1) AND (r.column2 = d.column2) AND (r.column3 = d.column3)
```

Output:

```
id  grp
1   1
2   1
1   2
3   2
5   2
2   3
4   3
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is easier than its actually it appear.

Let me know if it is not working with any other sample data.

```
drop table if exists #test_table
create table #test_table 
(
    id int,
    column1 varchar(20),
    column2 varchar(20),
    column3 varchar(20)
);

insert into #test_table (id, column1, column2, column3) 
values 
(1, 'A', 'B', NULL),
(2, 'A',NULL, 'C'),
(3, 'A', 'B', 'D'),
(4, NULL, 'D', NULL),
(5, 'A', 'B', 'D');

WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT t.id, 
                ISNULL(t.column1, t1.column1) col1, 
                ISNULL(t.column2, t1.column2) col2, 
                ISNULL(t.column3, t1.column3) col3, 
                t1.id AS tid, 
                ISNULL(t1.column1, t.column1) col4, 
                ISNULL(t1.column2, t.column2) col5, 
                ISNULL(t1.column3, t.column3) col6
         FROM #test_table t
              INNER JOIN #test_table t1 ON ISNULL(t.column1, t1.column1) = ISNULL(t1.column1, t.column1)
                                           AND ISNULL(t.column2, t1.column2) = ISNULL(t1.column2, t.column2)
                                           AND ISNULL(t.column3, t1.column3) = ISNULL(t1.column3, t.column3)
         WHERE t1.id > t.id),
     CTE1
     AS (SELECT *, 
                DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                ORDER BY col4, 
                         col5, 
                         col6) rn
         FROM CTE)
     SELECT DISTINCT 
            t.id, 
            ca.rn
     FROM #test_table t
          CROSS APPLY
     (
         SELECT c.id, 
                c.tid, 
                rn
         FROM cte1 c
         WHERE t.id = c.id
               OR t.id = c.tid
     ) ca
     ORDER BY rn;
```

`For optimize query` : Please throw real table structure.Total number of record and how many rows are require in resultset ?

Is there any restriction that  column1,column2,column3 will contain only certain value.Or they can contain anything ?